# Changing the color of an icon with jQuery while typing in a text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a textbox and an envelope icon for eMail inside it like this:

```
<input id="AdminEmail" name="AdminEmail" style="width:100%;padding-right:30px;" type="text" value="">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope  form-control-feedback" style="right: 10px; line-height: 27px; color: lightblue"></span>
```

And then I have added `jQuery` to change the color of the eMail icon if the email they are typing is or is not correct.  It worked when I used "`alert`" but did not work when I wanted to actually change the color instead of showing `alert`.

```
$("#AdminEmail").keyup(function () {
    var $email = $(this).val();
    validateEmail($email);
});
function validateEmail($email) {
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    if (!emailReg.test($email)) {
        $(".glyphicon-envelope").CSS('color', 'red');
    } else {
        $(".glyphicon-envelope").CSS('color', 'blue');
    }
}
```

Comment: It's `.css()`, not `.CSS()`.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem there is that CSS needs to be lowercase.

```
$(".glyphicon-envelope").css('color', 'red');
```

If you want to be really clever, you can combine that whole section into

```
$(".glyphicon-envelope").css('color', emailReg.test($email) ? 'blue' : 'red');
```

Comment: One more thing with that-- "$email" is just an ordinary string, since that's what the "val" function returns. If you're using "$" in the variable name to indicate "jQuery object", that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Simple...

just change to .css('color'....)

No caps